# Can I create a butterfly animation effect with translate3D (css), or another css animation on a single image or element?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have an image of a butterfly, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Ari.jpg).

[image: butterfly]

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to make it look like its wings are opening and closing with a 3D CSS transform/translate or animation, but without having to split the image up into parts (it can be a background image of a div though if that helps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using background applied to two elements where each one will show only one half and then you simply rotate both on the Y axis.

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  margin:20px;
  display:flex;
  perspective:500px;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  padding-top:56%; /* ratio based on your image */
  flex:1; /* half the main element size */
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/DgMoHC5.jpg);
  background-size:200% 100%; /* twice bigger than the pseudo element to get half the image*/
  animation:left 1s linear infinite alternate;  
  transform-origin:right;
}
.box::after {
  background-position:right; /* get the right part of the image */
  animation-name:right;
  transform-origin:left;
}

@keyframes left{
  to {transform:rotateY(60deg)}
}
@keyframes right{
  to {transform:rotateY(-60deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

A more realistic animation with some translation:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 56%;
  flex: 1;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/DgMoHC5.jpg);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  animation: left 0.5s linear infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.box::after {
  background-position: right;
  animation-name: right;
  transform-origin: left;
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(80px) rotateY(-30deg)
  }
  to {
    transform:translateZ(0px) rotateY(50deg) 
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  from { 
    transform: translateZ(80px) rotateY(30deg)
  }
  to {
    transform:translateZ(0px) rotateY(-50deg) 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```